# How to do authentication just with session token consequence request in codeigniter PHP without using database?

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, api, authentication

I am newbie to REST api but I have done many projects with Codeigniter . I am having a problem API because I would like to improve performance for API particularly user authentication . My api is especially designed for android app . My current authentication api flow is as follow . Mobile user login to app by entering username and password . That is sent to the api and api validates username and password against database . Then return success message , ID and so on . But for the second api request , for example ,user want to retrieve somethings else from database , I have to validate against database then the new request is served . So every time , I have to validate username and password against database . Is there anyway to maintain user login state after user is logged in for the first time. I am using Codeigniter version 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array of sessions where
2. Index would be a sessionId (session Id should be a random and unique string).
3. Value of that array would contain user details
4. Pass that sessionId to the android application as well.
5. Every time android applications calls a web service it should send the session Id as well along with other parameters and on server you can check if that session Id is set or not

Comment: Can we use session just like this ? $_SESSION["key"] = "value" ? Does it only work for browser ? Its work for Mobile App as well ?

Comment: Codeigniter have its own way of setting the session I would recomend you to use that, but yes `$_SESSION["key"] = "value"` would work as it is a core PHP syntax and codeignitor is just a framework which uses php in background

Comment: Regarding your another question whether it would work with mobile application as well so my answer is that codeignitor is an MVC frmaework of PHP and PHP is a server side script. And to server it does not matters who the client is whether it is android, ios or windows device, the client would submit a request and server would process that request through PHP

Comment: No we cannot use $_SESSION for android to maintain state

Comment: yes we can not authenticate $_SESSION in android but the android application would be sending the sessionId to server and server would verify if that token is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should keep in mind that if server will go down by any failure then whether you want the sessions to be stored or all users will have to login again to avoid this problem you must use an external data store that must be as fast liek a memory and also does not gets sessions deleted if there is any failure now for this functionality i guess redis is the best approach. If you dont want to store them then use simple sessions and send the session id along that particular user and check it for every request hope it helps :)